# Draw a circle with a circle void inside with paperjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

Draw a steel pipe section in `paperjs`. It's only a circle with a void circle inside. Just like this:

[image: Typical steel pipe section]

So far I have tried joins, intersections, subtractions, adds, but I am not able to achieve that simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.subtract()` is the correct method. Found it in [paperjs.org examples](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/)

```
const outer = new paper.Path.Circle(position, diameter/2)
const inner = new paper.Path.Circle(position, diameter/2-thickness)
pipe_section = outer.subtract(inner)
```